Why is it not possible to remove Database.Stateful from a deployed batchable class?
I want to remove the Database.Stateful implementation for a Batchable class, but when I deploy to our packaging org to create a new pacakage I receive error:

Class nmspc.BatchClass: Interface, Database.Stateful, relationship
must be maintained: nmspc.BatchClass

I was wondering, why does Salesforce prohibit from changing an already deployed class from being a batch class that implements Database.Stateful, to a class that does not implement Database.Stateful? We have a class in our system that implements Database.Stateful, but this turned out to be unnecessary, therefore it's better to remove the Stateful implementation since this benefits the memory consumption.
I am curious about the theory behind this, because I really don't see why changing this implementation would effect the working (when Stateful is unnecessary) or would introduce any weird side effects. I see it as my responsibility to handle this.
This limitation is annoying since now I have to introduce a new class.

I think you have to stop the batchable job completely from all its future jobs, before editing it

Please [edit] the question to state the exact error you get when trying to deploy the revised code.

@prem22, would you not have the same issue with changing the internal working of a batchable class? I receive an error at deployment.

@PieterJacob If you going to make changes in Sandbox and deploy to Production, then, first you have to stop the batchable job performed by this Apex Class in Sandbox, make the changes, test if everything work as expected, stop all the batchable job performed by this class in Production and deploy the code from Sandbox to Production.
If you are only testing in Sandbox (my assumption initially), then, stop all the batchable job of this class, edit the code, save and queue the job again.

Thanks for the edit. Not something I've seen before. Instead of just removing the interface you could perhaps first delete the batch on the org then re-introduce it without the implements Database.Stateful. Alternatively, mark all properties you don't want to be stored in the state as transient so they don't take up space in the stored state.

my theory would be that , since the Stateful interface is necessary for maintaining state , you should cross check the code for any places where you have defined / set field values/ properties on the class,and take those out before trying to deploy.
Also, I'd go with the advice of @prem22 to first abort the batch job as well before attempting deployment

I receive this error not when deploying to a sandbox or production, I deployed it to our packaging org to create a package. Therefore I don't think it is related.
